# Why the statement isn't correct?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a statement thay says:

> If they are formed, 5-letter words (with or without meaning) with the
>   letters of the word **PROBLEMA**, So which one (s) of the following
>   statements is (are) true (s)?
>
> I) 120 words contains only consonants.
>
> II) 240 words have E and A at the extremes.
>
> III) 7! words starts with L

Then, my development was:

$I)$ True, because taking into consideration only consonants is equal to $5!=120.$

$II)$ True, because if I have $E\ \_\ \_\ \_\ A$ and, $A\ \_\ \_\ \_\ E$, so I have two cases, and for each case must take $3$ letters, of $6$, importing the order, since $ABC$ will be different than $BAC$, then it is a variation, whose formula is
$$\frac{n!}{(n−r)!},$$

so $\Large\frac{6!}{(6−3)!}$ $\cdot 2!=120\cdot 2!=240.$

$III)$ True, because if the word start with
$${\large L\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_}\ ,$$

I have $7!$ of ordering the other elements, since it is a circular permutation, because $L$ is fixed.

My problem is that the correct answer must be only I) and II), I would like to know, why the III) is incorrect and also if there is a faster procedure for my answers I) and II)

Comment: You overlooked the requirement that the word have only $5$ letters.  You calculated the answer in III as if the word used all eight letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

III is false. $\dfrac{7!}{3!}$ words start with an L. There are only five letters in the generated word. $7!$ would imply there are 8 letters in this word.

And your methodology for figuring out I and II seemed appropriate to me. I cannot think of a "faster" method.

Answer (score 2):

$L$ is in the first letter, you have $4$ more letters to fill in out of $7$ letters.

Hence it should be $$7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4=\frac{7!}{3!}$$